# MySQL: Trying to understand SELECT query to fetch nearby locations

Tags: mysql, database, google-maps

While going through many SO questions on how to find nearby locations when we are having latitudes and longitudes stored in database, I many times came across [this](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf) presentation by Alexander Rubin (who was Senior Consultant, MySQL AB)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE geodist (IN userid int, IN dist int)
BEGIN
    declare mylon double; declare mylat double;
    declare lon1 float; declare lon2 float;
    declare lat1 float; declare lat2 float;

-- get the original lon and lat for the userid
    select longitude, latitude into mylon, mylat from users where id=userid limit 1;

-- calculate lon and lat for the rectangle:
    set lon1 = mylon-dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
    set lon2 = mylon+dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
    set lat1 = mylat-(dist/69); 
    set lat2 = mylat+(dist/69);

-- run the query:
    SELECT destination.*, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((orig.lat - dest.lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) + COS(orig.lat * pi()/180) * COS(dest.lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((orig.lon - dest.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance FROM users destination, users origin WHERE origin.id=userid and destination.longitude between lon1 and lon2 and destination.latitude between lat1 and lat2 having distance < dist ORDER BY Distance limit 10;
END $$
```

If I understand it correct there are two tables involved here. `destination` that has columns `longitude`, `latitude`. And `users` that has also columns `longitude`, `latitude` and `id`. The procedure gets userid and distance as input parameters and finds out location of user from `users` and then rows in `destination` which are nearby to the user.

Now, I am relatively new to MySQL hence finding it difficult to understand the procedure especially last SELECT query he has mentioned. Please can someone explain my doubts:

1. What are orig.lat, dest.lat, orig.lon, dest.lon & origin.id ? I couldn't find its references before in this procedure.
2. What does it mean by `FROM users destination, users origin`? If we querying two tables shall we not have comma in between their names? Also there is no mention of entity `origin` before.

Comment: Have you actually used this Procedure? The references to orig. and dest. do not seem to have actual tables defined in the query (unless I am missing something) so I do not think this will work. Possibly they are meant to be the `destination` and `origin` table alias` of the `users` table?

Comment: No I am trying to use but its not working. Yes Vatev's answer suggests same, they are aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses only one table - `users`, with two aliases: `origin` and `destination`.

Origin is used to find the location of the given user and destination is used to find the other users within a given distance.

The where clause uses `between` to find the users within the minimum bounding rectangle of the circle with a radius `dist` for performance reasons, and then those get additionally filtered to the desired circle with `having distance < dist`.

Also the 1-st query seems a bit redundant, the whole thing can be done with a single query.

Comment: That cleared lot of air. So `users destination` and `users origin` is how we refer alias of tables? or dot is missing?

Comment: The relevant bit of syntax is something like this: `FROM <table> <optional alias>, <another table> <another optional alias> WHERE <table or alias>.<field name>`. `users destination` and `users origin` define the aliases, `.` is used to refer to them.

Comment: So, when he says `orig.lat` and `dest.lat` he refers to columns in `users` only, latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find nearby location from database, you should use **[Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)**.

For example, you can encode 57.64911,10.40744 to `u4pruydqqvj` by Geohash, and then put it in database.

If you want to find location within 19m. You can use `WHERE geohash LIKE 'u4pruydq%'` in MySQL

If you want to find location within 2.4km, use `WHERE geohash LIKE 'u4pruy%'`.

Calculate every distance in MySQL is too low efficiency.

Comment: That's incredible :) Know any standard function producing Geohash? (Although I am Googling around the same)

Comment: @Atul You can find libraries for different programming language in the external links part in wiki page

Comment: Just for the record, MySQL has the ST_GeoHash function now. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-geohash-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's discuss the second part of your question:

In the last Select Query, there is only one table involved which is 'users'. Its been used twice. 'destination' and 'origin' are used as the aliases of this table. This way you can compare every single row with the other rows within the same table using different aliases. I am also not sure but its an alternative of Self Join.

As the procedure is written to find all the users within a certain range of distance (which is defined by creating a rectangle using longitude and Latitude values).

In the first select query, he only selected 'ONE' record from the users table and that record becomes the origin or the base record. The writer used two aliases of the same table i.e. 'origin' becomes the base user record and 'destination' is used to find out all the users located within the rectangular region in the neighborhood. That's why the writer used 'Select destination.*' which will list all the records of users table which fulfill the Where clause criteria (range of distance).

The mathematical formula just calculates the distance of the nearby users from the origin. The where clause matches the userid (input of the procedure) with the origin.id as its our base record and every record should be compared with this record.

I think 'dest' and 'orig' should be 'destination' and 'origin' as it makes more sense to use the same aliases and I assume it can be a mistake.

I hope at this stage you would have understood what 'origin.id' means. It's simple; origin is the alias of users table so 'id' is actually a column of users table.

I hope my explanation helped you!

Comment: _'dest' and 'orig' should be 'destination' and 'origin' as it makes more sense_ you are right.  orig.lat, dest.lat, orig.lon, dest.lon actually confused me a lot. Many thanks for detailed explanation.